# React JS Uncaught Reference Error: function not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call shuffleCards when the upon a click event in a ReactJs component. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: shuffleCards is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        count: 0
    };
}

shuffleCards(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        j = 0,
        temp;

    while (i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));

        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

handleClickEvent(event) {
    var cards = [
        {txt: "A",
        isDisplayed: false},
        {txt: "B",
        isDisplayed: false},
        {txt: "C",
        isDisplayed: false}
    ];
    if (this.state.count == 0) {
        cards = shuffleCards(cards);
    }

}
```

Comment: `this.shuffleCards`

Comment: @zerkms wow can't believe i didnt think of doing that. it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 32):

**EDIT** Just saw the comments and that **zerkms** already provided you with the solution. I'll leave my answer for clarification purposes.

---

Your problem is that inside the `handleClickMethod`, you are calling `shuffleCards` instead of `this.shuffleCards`

```
shuffleCards(array) {
  // ...
}

handleClickEvent(event) {
    // ...
    if (this.state.count == 0) {
        cards = this.shuffleCards(cards); // here you should use `this.`
    }
}
```

The reason is because `shuffleCards` method is defined on your component, which is accessible from its methods via the `this` property.

If you defined `shuffleCards` within the `handleClickMethod`, then you could call it without accessing `this`:

```
handleClickEvent(event) {

    function shuffleCards(array) {
      // ...
    }

    // ...
    if (this.state.count == 0) {
        cards = shuffleCards(cards); // here you don't need `this.`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Would this work for you? Demo here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/qaRdgX

You missed `this` when referring to `shuffleCards` in the `handleClickEvent` method.

```
shuffleCards(array) {
  // logic here
}

handleClickEvent(event) {
  cards = this.shuffleCards(cards);
}

render() {
  return (
    <button onClick={this.handleClickEvent.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

And i upgrade "**react-scripts**" and fix this problem.

Probaply fix this.

```
npm i react-scripts
```